# How do I create a ID based on multiple values in different columns in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to create an ID based in multiple values in different columns in Power query.

The idea is to check the following values:

```
 IF
        ID_STORE = 1
        ID_PRODUCT = 1
        ID_CATEGORY = 1
        SALE_DATE = 01/01/2018
        ID_COSTUMER = 1

THEN CREATE THE SAME ID FOR THE ROWS THAT HAVE THIS INFO.
```

The idea is to check the rows that have that info (1 and 01/01/2018) in multiple columns (ID_STORE, ID_PRODUCT, ID_CATEGORY etc..).

Thanks in advance.

Obs: This is my first post, so feel free to correct me in any manner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an 'AND' clause to your 'OF' statement;

```
if [ID_STORE] = 1
    and [ID_PRODUCT] = 1
    and [ID_CATEGORY] = 1
    and [SALE_DATE] = Text.ToDate("01/01/2018")
    and [ID_COSTUMER] = 1 then
1 else 0
```

Comment: Your syntax has some issues. The `if`, `and`, `then`, and `else` need to be lowercase and the column names need to be bracketed (e.g. `[ID_STORE]`).